# My flutter app crash on physical android 12 not on simulator after add local_notification

Tags: android, flutter

my app crash, only with android 12 mobile, I have only add flutter_local_notification package

I have add

```
implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
```

But my user have always crash even this add

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;Lj$/util/function/Consumer;)V in class Landroidx/window/extensions/layout/WindowLayoutComponent; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.window.extensions.layout.WindowLayoutComponent' appears in /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar)
      at androidx.window.layout.ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.registerLayoutChangeCallback (ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.java)
      at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invokeSuspend (WindowInfoTrackerImpl.java)
      at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke (WindowInfoTrackerImpl.java)
      at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke (WindowInfoTrackerImpl.java)
      at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely (SafeFlow.java)
      at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect (AbstractFlow.java)
      at androidx.window.java.layout.WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter$addListener$1$1.invokeSuspend (WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter.java)
      at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java)
      at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.java)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8855)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: What version of ` flutter_local_notification` are you using?

Comment: I use flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.1+1

Comment: notification is not call/ not init at the launch of app, the app crash at the launch. It seems to be located in the android build.gradle